# Removing bouncing when moving down slopes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the basic CharacterController code from the Unity documentation and I fixed this on my controller by just adjusting the `verticalVelocity` amount from the default **-2f** to **-6f** but I'm trying to not make the **-6f** apply constantly but only when I'm on an angle moving downwards.

So I created code using a Raycast and `Vector3.SignedAngle` to check what angle I'm on and which direction I'm moving, but no matter where I add the `verticalVelocity = -6f` variable inside of the Raycast, it doesn't work unless I place it outside of that Raycast but then it will override the default **-2f** value which is not good.

I believe the `if (velocity < 0)` statement might also be contributing to this issue but I'm unsure of how to combine that with my Raycast code.

```
// Update()

if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
{
    velocity.y = -2f;
}

if (isGrounded && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 2f))
{

    hitPointNormal = hit.normal;    
    float signedAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(hit.normal, Vector3.up, transform.right);

    if (signedAngle < 0.1f) // Player is moving downwards on an angle
    {
        if (isOnAngledSurface)
        {
            Debug.Log("Angle <");
            verticalVelocity = -6f; // prevent bouncing down slopes
            speed = 5f;
            isOnAngledSurface = false;
        }
     }
     if (signedAngle > 30f) // Player is moving upwards on an angle
     {
         if (!isOnAngledSurface)
         {
             Debug.Log("Angle >");
             speed = 2.5f
             isOnAngledSurface = true;
         }
     }
}
else
{
    if (isOnAngledSurface)
    {
        // Revert speed to default when no longer on an angle
        speed = 5f;
        isOnAngledSurface = false;
    }
}
```

What happens during run time is that my `verticalVelocity` starts at **-2f** and stays at that value no matter the angle I'm on or direction I'm moving in.